# JavaScript gets stopped on my device after 3-5 minutes turned off display

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I implement GPS signal tracking in my WebView android app and it can get continued while device display is turned off.

Prevent to stop javascript while turn off display.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to android operating system. For battery optimization android kill all processes running in the background. so that's why it stop working after some time. you need some permission (Like Batter Optimization) and some service that run in background.

Comment: CLose, but not quite.  This is Doze mode.  It isn't killing the process, but its limited to only executing every 15 minutes or so.  See https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby